# How to lock a resource in Python with multiple compatible owners

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, locking

I have a multi-threaded application with a shared resource. There are two types of threads, `A` and `B`, that access this shared resource. Any number of threads of the same type can simultaneously access the resource without a race condition, as long as there are no threads of the other class also accessing the resource.

Currently, I have a normal lock protecting the shared resource, to avoid the possible race conditions that occur when the incompatible thread functions access the resource at the same time. However, most of the threads are of type `A`, and the shared resource involves network requests so it takes quite a performance hit to not allow these to run simultaneously.

Is there a priority lock data structure in Python that allows multiple owners of the same "type", such that if there are a lot of thread `A`'s and a thread `B` tries to acquire the lock, no more thread `A`'s will be able to acquire it until the thread B has acquired it, and once it has, all the thread `A`'s will wait until it has released the lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a possible aproach would be to have an extra "master' thread in charge of allowing A or B threads alternatively.
I think it could be acomplished with semaphores.
There should be two semaphores `Asem` and `Bsem`.
The master thread initially release Asem n times allowing n A threads to access shared data. Sleep for some time and then acquire `Asem` n times. After that there are no A thread accesing the shared data so 
acquire BSem m times, sleep, acquire, and repeat all over.
In turn the A and B threads should acquire their respective semaphore to access shared data.

```
import threading
from time import sleep 

Asem = threading.Semaphore()
Bsem = threading.Semaphore()

def master():
    while True:
        Asem.release()
        Asem.release()
        Asem.release()

        sleep(0.1)

        Asem.acquire()
        Asem.acquire()
        Asem.acquire()

        Bsem.release()
        Bsem.release()
        Bsem.release()

        sleep(0.1)

        Bsem.acquire()
        Bsem.acquire()
        Bsem.acquire()
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea for a workaround. I will see if I can get this to work. Thread B is like a "reset" thread that only runs occasionally, so to minimize latency for both threads I will set a lower sleep time for it.

Comment: I used a variation of this with a BoundedSemaphore, which ended up working for my specific thread constraints. However, I am interested in a more generic solution, assuming it's even possible without a new primitive.